# C# Linq search inside object linked property

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, linq, linq-to-sql

i'm trying to do some search inside some attributes of my object set but i'm getting some trouble on the right way to mount my linq query, i have my VT_Video class which has its attributes and some linked objects

```
public partial class VT_Video
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string title { get; set; }
    public string description { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<VT_VideoTag> VT_VideoTag { get; set; }
}

public partial class VT_VideoTag
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public int tagID { get; set; }
    public int videoID { get; set; }

    public virtual VT_Tag VT_Tag { get; set; }
    public virtual VT_Video VT_Video { get; set; }
}

public partial class VT_Tag
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string name { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<VT_VideoTag> VT_VideoTag { get; set; }
}
```

What i want to accomplish is search a `user given word` inside my `Video collection` by `VT_Video.title`, `VT_Video.description` and also by `VT_Video.VT_VideoTag.VT_Tag.name`, what i managed to do so far is only search the `title` and `description`:

```
var myVideos = db.VT_Video.Include("VT_VideoTag")
                          .Include("VT_VideoTag.VT_Tag")
                          .Where(vid =>
                                 vid.descricao.Contains(strBusca) ||
                                 vid.titulo.Contains(strBusca)).ToList();
```

Now, i know i can do what i want with some foreach and extra code but i wondered if it would be possible to do it using linq and also keep my code clean.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have not worked with LINQ to SQL much, but it seems like `.Any()` would satisfy your requirement:

```
var myVideos = db.VT_Video.Include("VT_VideoTag")
                          .Include("VT_VideoTag.VT_Tag")
                          .Where(vid =>
                                 vid.descricao.Contains(strBusca) ||
                                 vid.titulo.Contains(strBusca) ||
                                 vid.VT_VideoTag.Any(tag => tag.name.Contains(strBusca))).ToList();
```

Notice I added this clause:

```
vid.VT_VideoTag.Any(tag => tag.name.Contains(strBusca))
```

Which returns true if any tag in the collection has a name that contains your search string.

Comment: It worked on one side, it brought a video which has a tag named sandman but it didn't bring a video with the title sandman

Comment: @Terkhos `String.Contains` is case-sensitive, so if your title starts with a capital letter, and your tag name does not, then that makes sense.

Comment: @Terkhos You're very welcome!  I'm glad I could help.